# Within a D3.js network diagram, can I add a count badge to a node or link?

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to add a count badge to a node or link within a D3.js network diagram.  Like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you only have to adjust node and link rendering functions.

Edit: take a look at this example http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

The node creation - see node.enter(), using append method you can add anything to your node.

The link creation - see link.enter(), using append method you can add anything to your link.

Comment: As a newb to D3.js, could you give me a little more detail.  Are you suggesting that I change the rendering functionality of D3 itself, or is there a way to adjust it through the API?